# Interface 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable' not found

Tags: laravel-5

I checked production and it doesn't have Access folder too inside Auth directory but it doesn't output such error. Please help. I'm using Laravel 5.0.35.

Answer (score 1):

This file was added after Laravel 5.0: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/b1c79a9a8478b8950d1d23ffbea7eaba3dfc1d2e

You may:

- Update your laravel version: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0
- Do not use this contract (maybe it's a lib that you use who calls this contract).

Comment: I don't understand, production and local dev have the same version but the latter do not produce that error.

Comment: Ok. Does the folder exists on your local dev? If so, did you run composer install on production server?

Comment: Sorry it's not the latter but the former that do not produce error. My dev has that error. But anyway, thank you very much. I realized that the controller that has that code isn't in used anyway so I just deleted it and upgraded the Laravel.